# ZipDotNet creates same stream for randomfiles

Tags: c#-4.0, stream, zip

Im using the ZipDotNet library for C#.

I created a byte array with random data like this:

```
public static byte[] GetRandomBytes(int Length)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[Length];
            Random random = new Random();
            random.NextBytes(data);
            return data;
        }
```

Now I want to zip those bytes to a MemoryStream and return the MemoryStream as byte array too.

```
public static byte[] zipFileToStream(byte[] file)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
                {
                    zip.AddEntry("file.txt", file);
                    zip.Save(memStream);
                }
                return memStream.ToArray();
            }
       }
```

When I print out the returning byte array, then there are always the same bytes in?

Can anyone help me with my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the MemoryStrream Position to 0 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the whole output of zipFileToStream? ZIP archive has some headers for each file entry, and in your case number of first bytes would be the same each time.

Comment: This was not the problem. I didn't set MemoryStream position to 0. Now it works. Thanks